# How to identify nulls in csv files on S3 bucket while loading to RDS postgresql database?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-s3

I'm trying to read csv files on S3 bucket and load them to RDS postgresql Database.
Few columns in these files have null values which are represented as \N.
So I've used a command similar to this

```
SELECT aws_s3.table_import_from_s3 
( 'public.tabletest', 
'', 
'(FORMAT csv, HEADER true, DELIMITER '','', null ''\N'')', 
'my_bucket_name_only', 
'ciao/hello/filename.csv',
 'eu-west-1' );
```

While it was treating \N as null in numeric fields, it is treating \N as a different character in text fields and timestamp fields.
Is there a way to set them to null as well by making any changes to the above command?

Edit:
I have observed that the text fields and timestamp fields have null as "\N" whereas it is just \N for numeric and boolean fields. Hence, using force_null option and specifying text and timestamp columns solved the problem

Comment: Is the `\N` enclosed in quotes?  Please show a row of data.

Comment: `FORCE_NULL` from [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html), though that means specifying the column names.